# Why does my loop only working on some of it's iterations?... (using Jsoup to extract data)

Tags: java, jsoup

The items in my itemList are incomplete! For some reason from the 10th iteration of my loop to the last 
`el.select(".item").select(".img").select(".pic").select(".picRind").select(".picCore").attr("src")`

returns a empty string and I can't understand why
**0-9th** iteration is perfectly find though. I went through the html and my code should work for every li I'm iterating through.

```
private Document getHtmlDocument() throws IOException {
    document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    return document;
}

public List<AliExpressItem> getAliExpressItemList() throws IOException {

    Document document;
    Element ul;
    Elements ulLi;

    document = getHtmlDocument();
    ul = document.getElementById("hs-below-list-items");
    ulLi = ul.getElementsByClass("list-item");
    List<AliExpressItem> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Element el : ulLi) {

        AliExpressItem item = new AliExpressItem();

        item.setImage(el.select(".item")
             .select(".img")
             .select(".pic")
             .select(".picRind")
             .select(".picCore")
             .attr("src"));
        item.setDescription(el.select(".item")
             .select(".info")
             .select("h3")
             .select("a")
             .text());
        item.setPrice(el.select(".item")
             .select(".info")
             .select(".price")
             .select(".value")
             .text());

        itemList.add(item);
    }

    return itemList;

}
```

Theres a ul with 48 li's inside. The above code should work for all 48 li's

```
<li qrdata="|32805326364|cn1511315262" pub-catid="200247142" sessionid="201711160635492248862329348280002056372" class="list-item list-item-first ">
<div class="item">
    <div class="img img-border">
        <div class="pic">
            <a class="picRind history-item j-p4plog" href="//www.aliexpress.com/item/Hot-Sale-Novelty-Toys-Hand-Spinner-Anti-stress-toys/32805326364.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.1.Lwk2KD&amp;s=p&amp;ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10130_10345_10324_10342_10547_10325_10343_10546_10340_10341_10548_10545_10541_10562_10084_10083_10307_5680011_10178_10060_10155_10154_10056_10055_10539_10312_10059_10313_10314_10534_10533_100031_10103_10073_10102_10594_10557_10558_10596_10142_10107,searchweb201603_14,ppcSwitch_5_ppcChannel&amp;btsid=6350c066-2194-4756-b1f7-ed7e1b0028e1&amp;rmStoreLevelAB=0" target="_blank" data-spm-anchor-id="2114.search0204.3.1"><img class="picCore pic-Core-v" src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1RUjgQFXXXXayXXXXq6xXFXXX4/Hot-Sale-Novelty-Toys-Hand-font-b-Spinner-b-font-Anti-stress-toys-fidget-font-b.jpg_220x220.jpg" alt="Hot Sale Novelty Toys Hand Spinner Anti stress toys fidget spinners For Autism and ADHD reliever stress spinner(China)"></a>
                        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="info">

        <h3>

            <a class="history-item product j-p4plog" href="//www.aliexpress.com/item/Hot-Sale-Novelty-Toys-Hand-Spinner-Anti-stress-toys/32805326364.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.2.Lwk2KD&amp;s=p&amp;ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10130_10345_10324_10342_10547_10325_10343_10546_10340_10341_10548_10545_10541_10562_10084_10083_10307_5680011_10178_10060_10155_10154_10056_10055_10539_10312_10059_10313_10314_10534_10533_100031_10103_10073_10102_10594_10557_10558_10596_10142_10107,searchweb201603_14,ppcSwitch_5_ppcChannel&amp;btsid=6350c066-2194-4756-b1f7-ed7e1b0028e1&amp;rmStoreLevelAB=0" title="Hot Sale Novelty Toys Hand Spinner Anti stress toys fidget spinners For Autism and ADHD reliever stress spinner" target="_blank" data-spm-anchor-id="2114.search0204.3.2">Hot Sale Novelty Toys Hand <font><b>Spinner</b></font> Anti stress toys fidget <font><b>spinners</b></font> For Autism and ADHD reliever stress <font><b>spinner</b></font></a>
                        </h3>

                                                                            <span class="price price-m">
                        <span class="value" itemprop="price">US $1.99</span>
                                                        <span class="separator">/</span>
                            <span class="unit">unidad</span>
                                                </span>



                                            <strong class="free-s">Envío gratis</strong>

                                                                        <div class="rate-history">
                                        <span rel="nofollow" class="order-num">
                        <a class="order-num-a j-p4plog" href="//www.aliexpress.com/item/Hot-Sale-Novelty-Toys-Hand-Spinner-Anti-stress-toys/32805326364.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.3.Lwk2KD&amp;s=p&amp;ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10130_10345_10324_10342_10547_10325_10343_10546_10340_10341_10548_10545_10541_10562_10084_10083_10307_5680011_10178_10060_10155_10154_10056_10055_10539_10312_10059_10313_10314_10534_10533_100031_10103_10073_10102_10594_10557_10558_10596_10142_10107,searchweb201603_14,ppcSwitch_5_ppcChannel&amp;btsid=6350c066-2194-4756-b1f7-ed7e1b0028e1&amp;rmStoreLevelAB=0#thf" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" data-spm-anchor-id="2114.search0204.3.3"><em title="Pedido totales"> Ventas (0)</em></a>
                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    <div class="info-more">

            <div class="aplus-sp-main">
                                    <div class="sp-box">
                                                                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="store-name-chat">
            <div class="store-name util-clearfix">
                                           <a href="//www.aliexpress.com/store/1308215?spm=2114.search0204.3.4.Lwk2KD" title="Alisa's cabin" class="store j-p4plog" target="_blank" data-spm-anchor-id="2114.search0204.3.4">Alisa's cabin</a>
                                </div>




        </div>

                                                    <a class="score-dot" href="//www.aliexpress.com/store/feedback-score/1308215.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.5.Lwk2KD" rel="nofollow" data-spm-anchor-id="2114.search0204.3.5"><span class="score-icon-new score-level-22" id="score1" feedbackscore="1,276" sellerpositivefeedbackpercentage="93.7"></span></a>



                <div class="add-to-wishlist">
            <a class="atwl-button j-p4plog" href="javascript:;" data-product-id="32805326364" data-batman-id="ja2kvte8" data-spm-anchor-id="2114.search0204.3.6">Añadir a Lista Deseos</a>
        </div>

        <input class="atc-product-id" type="hidden" value="32805326364">
        <input class="atc-product-standard" type="hidden" value="">
    </div>
<a href="//help.aliexpress.com/complaint/aeReportIntro.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.7.Lwk2KD&amp;product_id=32805326364&amp;b_login_id=cn1511315262" class="report-item" style="display: none;" title="Denunciar producto fraudulento" target="_blank" data-spm-anchor-id="2114.search0204.3.7"></a></div>
```

Comment: Please provide HTML document. It  will be helpful to debug

Comment: where  ? I don't see